# Odoo : Too many redirect, can't connect

Tags: python, loops, logging, odoo

my database crashed yesterday when I upgraded a module, I restored a backup and now I get this:

```
2016-05-27 09:19:53,140 10630 INFO DBTEST3 werkzeug: 192.168.1.20 - - [27/May/2016 09:19:53] "GET /web?db=DBTEST3 HTTP/1.1" 302 -
2016-05-27 09:19:53,605 10630 INFO DBTEST3 openerp.modules.loading: loading 1 modules...
2016-05-27 09:19:53,649 10630 INFO DBTEST3 openerp.modules.loading: 1 modules loaded in 0.01s, 0 queries
2016-05-27 09:19:53,670 10630 INFO DBTEST3 openerp.modules.loading: loading 31 modules...
2016-05-27 09:19:53,892 10630 INFO DBTEST3 werkzeug: 192.168.1.20 - - [27/May/2016 09:19:53] "GET /web?db=DBTEST3 HTTP/1.1" 302 -
2016-05-27 09:19:54,100 10630 INFO DBTEST3 openerp.modules.loading: loading 1 modules...
2016-05-27 09:19:54,108 10630 INFO DBTEST3 openerp.modules.loading: 1 modules loaded in 0.01s, 0 queries
2016-05-27 09:19:54,161 10630 INFO DBTEST3 openerp.modules.loading: loading 31 modules...
2016-05-27 09:19:54,383 10630 INFO DBTEST3 werkzeug: 192.168.1.20 - - [27/May/2016 09:19:54] "GET /web?db=DBTEST3 HTTP/1.1" 302 -
2016-05-27 09:19:55,041 10630 INFO DBTEST3 openerp.modules.loading: loading 1 modules...
2016-05-27 09:19:55,049 10630 INFO DBTEST3 openerp.modules.loading: 1 modules loaded in 0.01s, 0 queries
2016-05-27 09:19:55,070 10630 INFO DBTEST3 openerp.modules.loading: loading 31 modules...
2016-05-27 09:19:55,293 10630 INFO DBTEST3 werkzeug: 192.168.1.20 - -  [27/May/2016 09:19:55] "GET /web?db=DBTEST3 HTTP/1.1" 302 -
```

A huge a number of identical line like thoses, I won't paste them all obviously since they are strictly the same. And my browser says : "too many redirect". Where could this come from and how to fix this please?

Comment: Without your module nobody will be able to help you, as it is 99% caused by wrong fields definition.

Comment: Ok thanks, i'll look for this

Comment: Check the compute fields carefully

Comment: U might have used compute to create a function and u may have not defined the function